# Cannot find pfclnt90.dll. (SQL Server 2005 Enterprise)

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I need `pfclnt90.dll` for my `.NET` project, but standard SQL server edition doesn't have it.
I am asking you, could you send me `pfclnt90.dll`?

It placed here: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\pfclnt90.dll"`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to download a hotfix ([Bug #: 50000152 (SQL Hotfix)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917872)) from Microsoft that includes the pfcInt90.dll file you need.